# Getting Facebook Permissions from FBJS like normal apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an FB app which is going to use the Javascript SDK only, not the PHP library or any server side code. When I try to ask permissions from users for the first login to my application the permissions dialogue JS SDK shows is the pop-up one, used for FB Connect, but I want it to redirect the first time user to the normal application permissions page, and I want to do it using the JS SDK. Can someone please help me with this.

FYI : This is an application on apps.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure you can do this, but you could try to use the OAuth dialog (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) and use the **display** option set to `page`.

Let me know if that works.